# How to iterate over a map in XQuery?

Tags: xpath, xquery, saxon, xquery-3.0

Let's say I have map defined in XQuery like this:

```
declare namespace map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map";
let $x := map{'a':1, 'b':2}
```

How do I iterate through `$x` without knowing the keys?

For example:

```
for $key, $value in $x
(: Some processing and output :)
```

Comment: (BTW, this is functionality specified as part of the as-yet-unreleased XQuery 3.1, not 3.0; presumably you're using one of the engines frontrunning the spec).

Answer (score 4):

From [the BaseX wiki on XQuery 3.1 features](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/XQuery_3.1#Maps):

> The fact that a map is a function item allows it to be passed as an argument to higher-order functions that expect a function item as one of their arguments. As an example, the following query uses the higher-order function `fn:map($f, $seq)` to extract all bound values from a map:
>
> ```
> let $map := map { 'foo': 42, 'bar': 'baz', 123: 456 }
> return fn:for-each(map:keys($map), $map)
> ```

---

So, let's say that you wanted to call `do-some-processing()` with each key and value:

```
declare namespace map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map";
declare variable $map := map{'a':1, 'b':2};

declare function local:do-some-processing($key, $value) {
  (: deciding what to put here is your problem, not mine :)
  <key id="{$key}">{$value}</key>
};

fn:for-each(
  map:keys($map),
  function($k) { local:do-some-processing($k, $map($k)) }
)
```

Comment: what if I want to do something more sophisticated to the keys. See updated question than just output it's value

Comment: Then you'd replace the `$map` (calling the map itself as a function with the key as an argument) with a function that does... whatever more sophisticated thing you want. If you want a better answer, you'll need to provide a better question.

Answer (score 2):

Both of my examples return the key with the value incremented by `1`.

The more "imperative" way would be to get a list of all keys, loop over them and look up the values for each of them:

```
declare namespace map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map";
let $x := map{'a':1, 'b':2}
for $key in map:keys($x)
return $key || $x($key) + 1
```

A more elegant, functional approach would be to use `map:for-each` to "map" a (possibly anonymous) function onto the map (this is the term in functional programming when applying a function to each value of a list or sequence):

```
declare namespace map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map";
let $x := map{'a':1, 'b':2}
return map:for-each($x, function($key, $value) { $key || $value + 1 })
```

Unlike for most other XQuery features and functions, the BaseX documentation (which usually limits to BaseX-specific contents) offers a rather easy to read and understand reference and tutorial on the [XQuery map feature](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Map_Module).